# GIT entered wrong password, can't clone anymore

Tags: git, github

I just wanted to make a clone of a private repositoy from Github, and the prompt showed up and asked for my login details. 
I made a typo, but I don't get a second try. If I try to clone again I get the following message:

```
Cloning into 'name'...
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/owner/name.git/'
```

I want to set a default password and username for my git, because I will only use 1 Github account. How do I get to set my username and password?

I found many things online, but none that were a clear command to set your credentials.

Thanks in advance

Comment: on which OS? Linux, Windows, MacOS? The login/password is often stored in credential manager of the OS...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clear+credentials

Comment: Windows10. I have no clue where to look for saved credentials..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove credentials from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git)

Comment: Not working for me..

Answer (score 9):

Try below solution which works for me:

1. Go to Windows Credential Manager. This is done in a EN-US Windows by pressing the Windows Key and typing 'credential'. In other localized Windows variants you need to use the localized term (See comments for some examples).

alternatively you can use the shortcut control /name Microsoft.CredentialManager in the run dialog (WIN+R)

2. Edit the git entry under Windows Credentials, replacing old password with the new one.